# Python function not running as expected

Tags: python, function

I don't understand what is wrong with my code, it isn't running at all. What am I possibly doing wrong, I am trying to use a function. I have tried changing the number of asterisks but that isn't working, I also tried using quotations.

Here is my code:

```
def my_function(**h):
  input('Pick a number:')
  print("     ", end="")
  for i in range (1,int(h)+1):
    print("%5d"%i, end="")

  print()
  print("_______"*12)

  for i in range(1,int(h)+1):
    print("%5d|"%i, end="")

    for j in range(1,int(h)+1):
      print("%5d"%(i*j), end="")
  
    print()
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error did you encounter?

Comment: On colaboratory it isn't working me, like it just isn't running, is it working for you, because it might just be my computer, I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your desired output is, but does this help?

```
def my_function():
  h = input('Pick a number:')
  print("     ", end="")
  for i in range (1,int(h)+1):
    print("%5d"%i, end="")

  print()
  print("_______"*12)

  for i in range(1,int(h)+1):
    print("%5d|"%i, end="")

    for j in range(1,int(h)+1):
      print("%5d"%(i*j), end="")
  
    print()

my_function()
```

Comment: Oh I see my mistake now. Thank you so much @rchurt!

Comment: No problem! Could you accept the answer by clicking the check on the left of it?